# How to create a automatic invoice no genadate to jtextfield

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I tried to devolope my app
so I wont to create a automatic invoice no genadate to this methrod

I tried this code

```
        try{
        connectDB();
        Statement st =  con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("select * from tbl_day_sheet_daily_income");

        while(rs.next()){
        txt_no.setText(rs.getString("DaySheet_no"));
        String s = rs.getString("DaySheet_no");
        s = txt_no.getText();
            int billNumber = Integer.valueOf(s);
            s = Integer.toString(++billNumber);
            txt_no.setText(s);
        }
        con.close();

         }catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
         }
```

but i use this code in this programme other window it will works well,

Please tell me what is the wrong and how to fix that
Thank you..

Comment: Maybe yout can help us by specifying what you think is wrong with it.  Any errors?

Comment: What is a 'genadate'? What does this have to do with Swing? Does it work from a command line app.?

Comment: The bill number should be generated by the database, otherwise you risk having two entries with the same bill number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
try {
    connectDB();
    Statement st =  con.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(DaySheet_no) FROM tbl_day_sheet_daily_income");
    if (rs.next()) {
        int billNumber = rs.getInt(1) + 1;
        txt_no.setText(Integer.toString(billNumber));
    }
    con.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.toString());
}
```

Comment: (Usagi Miyamoto) I try your method , but still it will show dialog box and nothing appear.Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: (Usagi Miyamoto) I try your method , but still it will show dialog box and nothing appear.Please help me to solve this problem                                           , This is the image in dialog box https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4S2mKqSVXdbY2xfVXhoMXBpUjg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just curious, what was the problem, what was he exception?